# Issue getting a child components size

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For the long story, I'm trying to reproduce this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/j_holtslander/pen/KQrWVy?page=1&) with React.

However, it requires the landing page's height (the gif in background), and I tried to get "mine" but for some reason, I'm having troubles working with refs.

Here is the parent component:

```
export default class Stadium extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            height: '',

        }
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.Landing);
    }

    render() {
        const { data, scrollClass } = this.state;
        return (
            data !== null &&
            [
                <Header key={"header"} scrollClass={scrollClass} />,
                <Landing key={"landing"} heightRef={(elem) => this.Landing = elem}/>,
                <Maps key={"maps"} gmapskey={data.g_map_key} />,
                <p>Taille du landing: {this.state.height}</p>,
                <Footer key={"footer"}/>

            ]
        )
    }
}
```

And here is my child component:

```
export default class Landing extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            [
                <header id="landing" className="white-text" key={"header"} ref={this.props.Landing}>
                    <div className="container">
                        <h1>Opacity on scroll</h1>
                        <p>The header element fades away.</p>
                    </div>
                </header>,

                <div id='nav-bg' key={"bg"} />
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

According to [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components) and [this jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bu725co3/), I should be able to get my component's object, but `console.log(this.Landing);` returns `undefined`.

What did I forget?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [`Refs and the DOM`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: i have not heard of `heightRef`, isn't it `ref={ elem => this.Landing = elem}`. Then your `this.Landing` will be the dom node, in which you can call whatever you need to get data like `this.Landing.offsetHeight`

Comment: @ArmanCharan ...I linked this in my question.

Comment: `this.props.Landing` doesn't exist. You want `this.props.heightRef`.

Comment: You're correct, my elements weren't the same, but even with your response I still get undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
<Landing key={"landing"} Landing={elem => { this.Landing = elem; }} /></Landing>
```

Inside `Landing`, change it to this:

```
<header id="landing" className="white-text" key={"header"} ref="header"></header>
```

Another problem:
- The `<p>` tag is missing a key value

**Note:**
You can use `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` to wrap your component, so it doesn't create an extra `<div>` and you don't have to provide a key value.

**Update:**
A common mistake when passing `props`:
`heightRef={(elem) => this.Landing = elem}` is same as
`heightRef={(elem) => { return (this.Landing = elem); }}`,
`heightRef={(elem) => { this.Landing = elem;  return (this.Landing); }}`
and `heightRef={(elem) => (this.Landing = elem)}`.

Which is completely **different** to `heightRef={(elem) => { this.Landing = elem; }}`
If it doesn't expect return a value, don't result it. It may cause side-effect.

There is the demo I tested on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oqkn10yjx6)

Comment: Don't worry about <p>, it's more for a test than a permanent element. However, for your answer, I keep getting "undefined"

Comment: @Jaeger https://codesandbox.io/s/oqkn10yjx6 I provided a codesandbox link to this problem, since it has better support on React.

Comment: I saw your link, however I can't manage to make it work on my project, it drives me crazy

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you but I resolved myself to copy and paste your code and... it worked. I think I missed out something obvious I guess. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Jaeger Using `ref` isn't very good practice in my opinion. Does pass the value with a callback function not an option?

Comment: Where does `elem` come from in `Landing={elem => { this.Landing = elem; }}`? How is that innner function being triggered? You should be using the built-in `ref` prop to get access to the dom node.

Comment: @Jaeger Thank you. I know. It's getting lil bit intense when you try to answer a question and help someone else. LMAO.

Comment: @Jaeger you might want to test the code in multiple scenarios, as I don't think that this will get you the correct value.

Comment: Eric Hasselbring nailed it on the head in the comments

Comment: Okay I'm seeing it now. It gets triggered in `Landing` when they assign `this.props.Landing` to the `ref` of the `header`. Wow, never seen this before, and that's probably for a reason. You should be assigning the ref wherever you are doing the height calculation, ie in `Stadium`.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda  I updated my answer. and just be clear when I'm writing the answer, the comment wasn't there.

Comment: My issue isn't with the syntax. Where did you ever learn to abstract a `ref` call like that? It totally breaks the React pattern of uni-directional flow from parent to child. You are essentially passing a function to the child which is using it to set the ref OF ITSELF and then also running that function in the parent to update a static class variable?? This is not only the wrong way to set a ref, but seems really error prone and is a nightmare to debug.

Comment: @FisNaN Ok so don't ask me why, but it seems that if I have a state named "data" (as in `this.state.data`), then your code doesn't work.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I don't. I'm trying to solve the existing problem. I agree what you said, and I already mentioned shouldn't use `ref` like this. But I also don't want to make the problem more complex than it should be.

Comment: @Jaeger Are your testing the code on a web-based IDE? You might need setup a proper project and try to debug with Chrome or Firefox

Comment: @FisNaN I'm working with Laravel and Webpacker Mix from PHPStorm, it handles Javascript in general pretty well so I'm not convinced that the problem comes from here

Comment: @Jaeger Take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660385/how-to-position-a-react-component-relative-to-its-parent You can pass a string  to `ref` in child component. I also updated my codesandbox

Comment: OMG please stop suggesting bad practices! SO is for helping other developers learn the correct way to do things. Yes you can "answer" the question by hacking things together, but that isn't helping OP or any future developers that come across this answer. @Jaeger be aware that string refs are deprecated and should not be used anymore https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda don't worry I opened a ticket on the React Github, they told me the same thing, but FisNaN answer still helped me figure the logic out ;)

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Using string ref is fairly common practice in React-Native.For example `wix/react-native-interactable`. Another example could be, you want to trigger [scroll to top] event on a child `FlatList`, and this button can only be seen when `FlatList` is not on the top.