# React child components positioning overlapping issue

Tags: css, reactjs

I have seen several questions with this issue, but none of the questions could help me solve my problem. I have a Parent component with three Child components.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import Header from "./Header";
import ChildOne from "./ChildOne"
import ChildTwo from "./ChildTwo"

class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <ChildOne />
        <ChildTwo />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

Each child component contains a simple `div`. I have applied the following styling to the components:

```
.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.childone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 480px;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
}

.childtwo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
}
```

I would expect the React components to render one under each other, with the first child positioned `top: 100px;` and the second one positioned `top: 580px;`

I need the positioning to be flexible since I'm building responsive components.

What happens instead, is that ChildTwo overlaps ChildOne.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660385/how-to-position-a-react-component-relative-to-its-parent) a possible answer is suggested, however, I can't understand how to apply the solution to my case. What would be the right way to achieve the needed positioning?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It's a CSS problem, not a React problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do it with absolute positioning.

Use `flexbox` css property : [Complete Guide Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

add `flex` class to your wrapper div and assign it with css:

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Now you can remove: `top` property from all child components.

Note that `flexbox` is fully responsive and it help you much more `absolute` positioning;

[Working Exmaple](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-cookies-reo9z)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I recreated your code and I was able to render all components one underneath the other one by giving the exact top values you mentioned.

> I would expect the React components to render one under each other,
>   with the first child positioned top: 100px; and the second one
>   positioned top: 580px;

However, the CSS styles you posted in this post has the "TOP" properties set to auto.

here is a copy of my live solution:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/sweet-dust-587oz

```
.header {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.childone {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 480px;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;//I changed this to top: 100px;
}

.childtwo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;//I changed this to top: 580px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I mentioned that the reason I want it to be automatically calculated is that I'm developing a responsive layout. And if I fix the top at 580px then I won't get the perfect view for a mobile device, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with CSS than with React. Your current HTML output looks like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="childone">child one</div>
  <div class="childtwo">child two</div>
</div>
```

Childone and Childtwo are not children of the header (if this is what you wanted to achieve?), they are children of the `div`. They are absolutely positioned, so they are going to orientate towards the nearest parent that is positioned relatively. They also have the same top value (auto), so they are overlapping. Change the top value of childtwo to `480px`, the box will appear right after chileone. If you want to have both after your header, add `top: 100px` to childone and `top: 580px` to childtwo (100px (height of the header) + 480px (height of childone))

To make it more obvious what happens, add `border: 1px solid red` to your elements

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I want to avoid specifying pixels is that I want to have a responsive layout, hence top: auto.