# How can I ensure that a ref is loaded when I need it to pass to another component?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I have a component which basically renders like so:

```
<div ref={containerRef}>
  <Child containerRef={containerRef} />
</div>
```

I do this because `Child`'s rendering logic is dependent upon the "bounding client rect" of the containing div-- the child uses the parent's left/top positions in order to calculate its own absolute position with JavaScript. By passing in the `containerRef` to `Child`, I am able to access `containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()` and its various positional attributes.

The problem is that on initial render, `containerRef` is not set. It isn't set until the second render.

How can I either A.) force a second render, B.) force it to be set on the first render (presumably impossible), C.) solve this problem in a different way such that the child can access its parent's container?

Perhaps if `Child` sets a ref on its own child HTML, I can simply use imperative code to access the parent of that node?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position a React component relative to its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660385/how-to-position-a-react-component-relative-to-its-parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600572/how-to-rerender-when-refs-change), using a callback ref with `useState` solves this (as opposed to `useRef` and without the callback syntax.)

That way, when the ref is set, a render is triggered. This solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)? The point is you want to observe position of node, isn't it? This achieves it and gives position to child as state.

Comment: I think that will have the same problem. If he uses that directly in the render code, the parent wont actually be rendered yet and thus there is nothing fot intersection observer API to observe.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that on initial render, containerRef is not set.

That's a use case for [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) which will run immediately after the DOM has been updated, but before the browser paint.

See [useEffect vs useLayoutEffect](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect).

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  // use containerRef.current
}, [])
```

> Perhaps if Child sets a ref on its own child HTML, I can simply use imperative code to access the parent of that node?

That's a use case for [`useImperativeHandle`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle), but I believe `useLayoutEffect` will be enough (you didn't provide a reproducible example).

Comment: Holy shit, that'll be exciting if I actually finally have a use case for this niche hook. I've always wondered if I ever would. I'll give this a shot and accept the answer later if it works, thanks.

Comment: By the way are you saying the code that handles position calculation inside `Child` should use `useLayoutEffect`?

Comment: I think `Child` should not know about positioning, therefore he should implement `useImperativeHandle`, while its parent will decide how to position him using `useLayout` and some logic.

Comment: This actually didn't help! What I ended up doing is using a callback ref with useState to trigger the render and that fixed it. `useLayoutEffect` doesn't help with triggering renders on its own, so having the ref go from null to not-null remains a problem.

Comment: `useLayoutEffect` in the child will run _before_ the parent gets to set the ref. (I tried both, callbackRef and useRef, with react 18.2.0). So I feel doing two renders by using `useState` is the only viable way.

If you really want to prevent double rendering, the child would have to traverse the DOM within its `useLayoutEffect` to find the right node.